# Print a List<String> to logcat

Tags: java, android, debugging, logcat, android-logcat

I can see that the log.d requires

```
Log.d(String TAG, String).
```

How do I print to the android debug logcat a List String instead of just a String?

Comment: I mean this as a serious question.  Why don't you just read the docs for `List` and see what methods are available?  you would have found `toString()`. It's quicker than creating a question here.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Make use of [toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString%28%29) method which is available for most common data structures:

```
Log.d("list", list.toString());
```

Above statement will give you the expected result if you declare your `List`/`Collection` using [Generic type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) defined in Java. Such as String, Integer, Long etc. Cause, they all have implemented `toString()` method.

**Custome Generic Type:**

But if you declare the `List` using your own custom type then you will not get proper output by just calling `list.toString()`. You need to implement `toString()` method for your custom type to get expected output.

**For example:**

You have a model class named `Dog` as below

```
public class Dog{
   String breed;
   int ageC
   String color; 
}
```

You declared a `List` using `Dog` type

```
List<Dog> dogList = new ArrayList<Dog>();
```

Now, if you want to print this List in `LogCat` properly then you need to implement `toString()` method in `Dog` class.

```
public class Dog{
   String breed;
   int age
   String color;

   String toString(){
       return "Breed : " + breed + "\nAge : " + age + "\nColor : " + color;
   } 
}
```

Now, you will get proper result if you call `list.toString()`.

Comment: For KOTLIN Use "data class".. It has toString() and all necessary methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (list != null && list.size() > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                        mStrp = mStrp + list.get(i).getdataname() + "/";
                        mStrD  = mStrD + list.get(i).getdata2name() + "/";
                    }

                    //if you want to delete last "/"
                mStrp = mStrLatPick.substring(0,mStrLatPick.length() - 1);

                    value = mStrp + mStrD;
                    Log.d("value",value);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the Array List element on the console.and also add , remove an element.

```
    ArrayList myFavAnimal = new ArrayList();

    myFavAnimal.add("Lion");
    myFavAnimal.add("Tiger");
    myFavAnimal.add("Leopard");
    Log.i("MyTag",myFavAnimal.get(0) +"");
    myFavAnimal.remove(1);
    Log.i("MyTag",myFavAnimal.toString());
    myFavAnimal.remove("Lion");
    Log.i("MyTag",myFavAnimal.toString());
```